# Google Chrome spell check confusion

Tags: google-chrome

I just saw something unusual behavior in Google Chrome's inbuilt spell check feature. This feature highlights wrong spellings with a red underline while typing in a textbox. But my doubt is, how can it under-line a the same word when all letters in the word are in small case, eg - facebook

and again when i type the same word with the first alphabet in Uppercase, eg - Facebook, the word is not underlined.

Here is the snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook only refers to one thing-the name of one particular website. That makes it a proper noun, and so it should be capitalized. That's in the same vein that "person" or "website" (generic common nouns) are not capitalized, but "Jim" and "Facebook" (referring to a specific person or website) are.

While writing this post, incidentally, I've found that Firefox has the same behavior-write firefox or facebook and you'll get the red line, but Firefox and Facebook are not flagged.

So, basically, Chrome is correctly flagging a misspelling, or at least a capitalization error. Facebook is correct, facebook is not.

Comment: you mean to say that this thing is related to English Grammar?

Comment: It would sure seem that way, especially given that Firefox does the same thing. Spellcheckers work from dictionaries of "correct" words, and since "facebook", and "firefox", and what have you, aren't correct words (only their capitalized versions are), it makes sense they're not in those dictionaries.